# Arrays not averaging out correctly using a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, while-loop

```
namespace Files_and_Arrays_II
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            int doctor = 0;
            double total = 0, average_sys = 0;
            string name, DocN;

            string[] doctors = new string[3] { "D. ABRAMS, MD", "D. JARVIC, MD", "T. PANOS, MD" };
            int[] systolic = new int[5];
            int[] diastolic = new int[5];

            OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                inputFile = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName);
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    name = inputFile.ReadLine();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        systolic[i] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                        diastolic[i] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    }

                    //Calculates average for systolic
                    for (int count = 0; count < systolic.Length; count++)
                    {
                        total += systolic[count];
                    }
                    average_sys = total / 5;

                    doctor = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    DocN = doctors[doctor];
                    listBox1.Items.Add(name + "\t" + average_sys + "\t" + DocN);

                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This is the file it is getting it from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfBEZ.png)

When running the program I get the following averages for systolic: 184.6 (correct), 312 (wrong).

I've tried resetting the array at the end of the loop but that solves nothing

Comment: the only code using the ``diastolic`` array is just used to populate it, there's nothing else referencing it.

Comment: Wheres the code calculating the diastolic average and outputting that result? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Did you intend to keep the `total` from one line while reading the next line? My guess is that you've just forgotten `total = 0` at the end of the inner loop.

Comment: Umm, you don't reset your `total`. FYI: You can easily find such errors -- like variables not having the value you believe/expect -- by using the debugger ([Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger))

Comment: And it's odd that you are doing this average calculation INSIDE your while loop. Load your arrays inside, calculate your average outside after they are loaded.

Comment: perhaps this question should be removed, doesn't server any purpose anymore for others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have pointed out the problem in this case, but it's a symptom of declaring variables at the top of the function. If you'd declared them close to where they are used, it would be obvious which variables apply to the whole function and which have a scope that only applies inside the loop.

Like this:

```
                string name = inputFile.ReadLine();

                //Calculates average for systolic
                double total = 0;
                for (int count = 0; count < systolic.Length; count++)
                {
                    total += systolic[count];
                }
                double average_sys = total / 5;

                int doctor = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                string DocN = doctors[doctor];
                listBox1.Items.Add(name + "\t" + average_sys + "\t" + DocN);
```

Even better, use `var` instead of setting the variable type in two places and risking getting it wrong.

Comment: Yep. And declaring everything at the top is a symptom of coding styles (and instructors) that evolved in the days when many languages required this, and have not evolved towards better practice. I've seen declaring variables at the top taught in schools as "better style". It was true once; it's not today. Welcome to programming, where everything you think you know is really just a snapshot of how things were at one point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting your variables for total and average for the second set of measurements.